# not $L^1$ convergent but point-wise almost everywhere convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need an example of a sequence of functions in $L^1$ like $\{{f_n}\}$ such that

$f_k \le f_{k+1}$ for every natural $k$ almost everywhere

$f_n$ is point-wise almost everywhere convergent

but $f_n$ is NOT $L^1$ convergent!

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$ f_n = \chi_{[0,n]}
$$
All convergence are w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$, $f_n \to 1$ pointwisely, but $\lVert f_n \rVert \to \infty$.